# setImage swift position

Tags: swift, xcode, image, uibutton

I’m new in programming with Xcode and Swift and it seems that I do not understand the language correct. I’m trying to create a button which changes the image when clicked and an animated popup of the menu. All works fine as long as I don’t change the image. As soon as I add the toggling of the button-image, the animation doesn’t do what it should do. 
I have the impression that some parameters are changed when I use ‘setImage’.

```
@IBAction func buttonMoreClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

   toggleButton(button: sender, imageOn: UIImage(named: "iconClose.png")!, imageOff: UIImage(named: "iconAdd.png")!)

    if (boolFirstClickButtonMore == false) {
        boolFirstClickButtonMore = true
        self.centerAddEventButton = self.buttonAddEvent.center
        self.centerAddGroceryButton = self.buttonAddGrocery.center
        self.centerAddTasksButton = self.buttonAddTasks.center           

        self.righttopAddEventLabel = self.labelAddEvent.frame.origin
        self.righttopAddGroceryLabel = self.labelAddGrocery.frame.origin
        self.righttopAddTasksLabel = self.labelAddTasks.frame.origin

        self.buttonAddEvent.center = self.buttonMore.center
        self.buttonAddGrocery.center = sender.center
        self.buttonAddTasks.center = sender.center

        self.labelAddEvent.frame.origin = self.buttonMore.frame.origin
        self.labelAddGrocery.frame.origin = self.buttonMore.frame.origin
        self.labelAddTasks.frame.origin = self.buttonMore.frame.origin
    }

    // If button 'MORE' is set then hide menu buttons
    if (boolSetMore) {
        boolSetMore = false
        sender.layer.backgroundColor = self.colorGreen.cgColor
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.buttonAddEvent.center = self.buttonMore.center
            self.buttonAddGrocery.center = sender.center
            self.buttonAddTasks.center = sender.center

            self.labelAddEvent.frame.origin = self.buttonMore.frame.origin
            self.labelAddGrocery.frame.origin = sender.frame.origin
            self.labelAddTasks.frame.origin = sender.frame.origin

            self.viewDisable.alpha = 0.0
            self.buttonAddEvent.alpha = 0.0
            self.buttonAddGrocery.alpha = 0.0
            self.buttonAddTasks.alpha = 0.0

            self.labelAddEvent.alpha = 0.0
            self.labelAddGrocery.alpha = 0.0
            self.labelAddTasks.alpha = 0.0

        })
    }
    else {
        boolSetMore = true
        self.viewDisable.alpha = 0.75

        self.buttonMore.layer.backgroundColor = self.colorDarkGreen.cgColor
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.buttonAddEvent.center = self.centerAddEventButton
            self.buttonAddGrocery.center = self.centerAddGroceryButton
            self.buttonAddTasks.center = self.centerAddTasksButton

            self.labelAddEvent.frame.origin = self.righttopAddEventLabel
            self.labelAddGrocery.frame.origin = self.righttopAddGroceryLabel
            self.labelAddTasks.frame.origin = self.righttopAddTasksLabel

            self.buttonAddEvent.alpha = 1.0
            self.buttonAddGrocery.alpha = 1.0
            self.buttonAddTasks.alpha = 1.0

            self.labelAddEvent.alpha = 1.0
            self.labelAddGrocery.alpha = 1.0
            self.labelAddTasks.alpha = 1.0
        })
    }

}
func toggleButton(button: UIButton, imageOn: UIImage, imageOff: UIImage) {
   if (button.currentImage == imageOn) {
        button.setImage(imageOff, for: .normal )
    }
    else {
        button.setImage(imageOn, for: .normal )
    }
}
```

When clicking on the buttonMore, three buttons and labels appear from the buttonMore. When clicking again, the three buttons and labels should move back to the buttonMore and alpha is set 0 (animated). This works fine but when I add the toggling of the image, the positions of the three buttons changes and the animations disappears. Anybody an idea?

Comment: What is toggling of image?

Comment: I mean with toggling of image that I change the image of the button every time it is clicked.

Comment: UIButton has different states like selected, default... you should set respective image for the state you need, in this case it would be selected state and just modify the isSelected property of UIButton